# How do I change recursive php breadcrumbs into links?

Tags: php, hyperlink, explode, breadcrumbs

I'm working an a shopping cart with a page called display.php.  This page is called repeatedly as you go through the navigation, always calling itself but querying for new, more specific things.  I am trying to make breadcrumbs that will provide links to previous pages, but it's proving to be tricky.

This part of display.php retrieves "id", which the query uses to find things, and breadcrumbs, which is the previous breadcrumbs string.  "id" is always added to the breadcrumbs string.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$breadcrumbs=$_GET['breadcrumbs'];
$breadcrumbs = $breadcrumbs." > ".$id;
echo $breadcrumbs
```

As the id variable is used to query for things, links are generated to go to display.php all over again but to query for something new and take the breadcrumbs string with it.
     `<a href="http://www.myurl.com/display.php?id='.$name.'&depth='.$sub_level.'&breadcrumbs='.$breadcrumbs.'"><img src="imagen/logo1.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><br>'. $name . '</a>`

Each time I go to a new page, the breadcrumbs display visibly, but how can I safely change these string statements into links?  an  can't carry another  string inside it safely.  I think it's possible if I explode the breadcrumb string with the > character as the delimiter.  How can I fix this up so it will display nice links in the breadcrumb string?

```
    $breadlist = explode(" > ", $breadcrumbs);

    $linkarray = array();
    foreach $breadlist as $breadlink
    {
        $linkarray($j) = "<a href=display.php?id=".$breadlink($j)."?breadcrumbs=".$breadcrumbs.">".$breadlist($j)."";
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two apparent problems (among some other small fixes):

1. You need to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) your URLs.
2. You need to access arrays with `[]`, not `()`.

Here is an example to get you started:

```
$breadlist = explode(" > ", $breadcrumbs);

$linkarray = array();
foreach( $breadlist as $breadlink)
{
    $url = 'display.php?id=' . $breadlink . '&breadcrumbs='.$breadcrumbs;
    $linkarray[] = '<a href="' . urlencode( $url) . '">' . $breadlink . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: This code was incredibly useful and nearly worked perfectly on its own.  Thank you so much for that, and introducing me to urlencode().  I just needed to make two adjustments.  First, I added a > at the end of the text for the link.  Then I did another foreach to echo them:foreach ($linkarray as $onelink)
{
 echo $onelink;
}

Comment: If you want to be clever, you can echo them in one line like this: `echo implode( '', $linkarray);`. Done!